# How to make img + text on same line in a nav element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a menu bar in top of my web-site, which works and looks nice with icons to the left and text to the right. My plan is to design it like this:

```
(Img) Service   (Img) Free installation    (Img) Free Delivery
```

The (Img) should of-cause be a nice icon instead :) - I have trouble to put the icons on the same line. What i have done so far:

**HTML**

```
<nav class="nav1">
    <li><a href="text.html">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="text.html">Support</a></li>
    <li><a href="text.html">text</a></li>
</nav>

<div id="user_logo">
    <img style="display: inline;" src="user.png" height="18" width="18">            
</div>
```

The user_logo should be placed to the left of the first element.

**CSS:**

```
#user_logo {
    margin: 0cm 0cm 0cm 25cm;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}

.nav1 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    display: block  
}
```

This method works visually, but when i do this with the margin, the navigation menu becomes unreasonable like you can't click on the links.

Is there an easier method to do it, or am i nearly there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there!

In order to horizontally align your nav, you are just missing this piece of CSS:

```
/* Missing this piece to have the NAV horizontal */
.nav1 li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

This basically tells all `<li></li>` elements nested in your 'nav1' class element to fall in the same line (think typeface.) Padding was added just for visual purposes, but is not necessary.

Here is a [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dd89rb0n/2/). Included is a refence to [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), which is a great utility for icons - in case you were looking for one :)